# Does flatness morphisms between ringed spaces implies the direct image sheaf is flat?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ be ringed spaces and $f: X\to Y$ be a morphism between them. We call $f$ flat at $x\in X$ if the natural morphism $\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(x)}\to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a flat map. We call $f$ is flat if $f$ is flat at all points in $X$.

> > My question is: if $f$ is flat, is it always true that $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is a flat $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module?

Edit: I found that the answer is negative in general, even for proper and flat morphism over schemes see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112781/about-the-definition-of-flat-morphism-flat-sheaf?rq=1) and [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65267/global-sections-of-flat-scheme-also-flat).

Comment: Note that a module is flat if and only if all its localizations are flat. That should answer your question for open affine sets, now unfold definitions.

Comment: @assaferan There are two problems: first, I am interested in not just schemes but general ringed spaces; second, even if we consider schemes, the fibers of $f$ need not to be affine.