# Stein factorization and flatness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

$\textbf{Question: }$ Suppose $X \xrightarrow{\phi} Y$ is a proper faithfully flat map of noetherian schemes and let $X \xrightarrow{f} Y' \xrightarrow{g} Y$ be the Stein factorization. Is either of $g$ or $f$ necessarily flat? I’d really like to see examples if these are false. In general, for a composite as above with $f$ faithfully flat, we have that $g$ is faithfully flat or flat iff $\phi$ is.

More generally, it seems like if $\phi = g \circ f$ is a factorization of a proper flat map with $g$ finite then $g$ is also flat. But I can't prove this.

This came up when I was thinking about how I would prove the connectedness principle in algebraic geometry (Let $X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper faithfully flat map with $Y$ the spectrum of a DVR. Then if the generic fiber is connected, so is the special fiber), and you can prove this with ZMT. The above result would give you a different proof. If $f$ in the Stein factorization above is faithfully flat then so is $g$ (by general properties) but because the generic fiber is connected $g$ is also an isomorphism on an open set, hence an isomorphism.

Googling around shows that it also came up in the comments here [Global sections of flat scheme also flat?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65267/global-sections-of-flat-scheme-also-flat) but without a resolution.

Comment: This might or might not be helpful: If $Y$ is reduced, then the flatness of $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is equivalent to its formation being compatible with arbitrary base-change. 

Comment: @Keerthi: What you say isn't true; e.g., if $Y$ is a dvr then $f_{\ast}O_X$ is always flat but its formation need not commute with any base change.

Comment: @LMN: Your statement of the connectedness principle is incorrect: let $Y = {\rm{Spec}}(R)$ for a dvr $R$ with fraction field $K$ and let $X = {\rm{Spec}}(R')$ for the integral closure $R'$ of $R$ in a quadratic Galois extension $K'/K$ in which the place of $R$ on $K$ is totally split.  The connectedness principle is essentially a deep result of Zariski which historically is related to the origin of Zariski's "Main Theorem".  It seems unlikely that there is a proof of the connectedness principle based on a flatness principle; I expect your question has a negative answer, but have no proof yet.

Comment: @LMN: Tong's answer in the MO thread you linked to is a counterexample for you (take his $X_n$ which is proper faithfully flat over $R/\pi^nR$). 


Comment: @kreck: Thanks for the correction. I should also say $\dim_{k(Y_0)} H^0(\mathcal{O}_{X_0}) = 1$ where $Y_0$ is the generic point of $Y$ and $X_0$ the fiber of the generic point. The proof (below) also works for the version of the connectedness thm. in Hartshorne (Ex III.11.4). There, assuming $k = \bar{k}$ you automatically have the dimension condition above, (because an open set of points have $k$ as the residue field) which is how I forgot it.

Comment: Here is a proof including the hypothesis:

Proof: The generic point $Y_0$ is an open set, and on this open set the finite morphism $g$ is an isomorphism by definition, hence a finite birational map. Since $Y$ is normal &  noetherian, ZMT applies and says not just that the fibers are connected by that $g_*(\mathcal{O}_{Y'}) = \mathcal{O}_X$ (the pf of ZMT in Hartshorne says this). So by construction $g = id$. Hence $\phi = f$ thus the fibers of $\phi$ are connected.

Comment: @kreck: You're absolutely right. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your "general guess" is not true, because of the following example.

A nodal cubic $Y$ has an étale (hence flat) double cover $\phi \colon X \to Y$, where $X$ is the union of two copies of the normalization $Y^{\nu}$ of $Y$, intersecting at two points.

Then $\phi$ factors as $\phi=\nu \circ f$, where $f \colon X \to Y^{\nu}$ is a non-normal double cover branched at $\nu^{-1}(p)$, where $p \in Y$ is the node,  and $\nu \colon Y^{\nu} \to Y$ is the normalization map.

In particular, $\nu$ is finite but *not* flat.

Of course, this does not give any counterexample about your question on Stein factorization, since the Stein factorization of $\phi \colon X \to Y$ is $\phi$ itself.